# Js стили для window.open() задаются с большой задержкой

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой скрипт, который открывает новое окно, например с вашим вк, и должен создать эффект "эпилепсии".

```js
let vkCopy = window.open('https://vk.com/im');
// 5 сек ждем, когда новое окно загрузится
setTimeout(() => {
  let current = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    if (current === 4) vkCopy.document.body.style.cssText = "background: lime !important";
    else if (current === 3) vkCopy.document.body.style.cssText = "background: red !important";
    else if (current === 2) vkCopy.document.body.style.cssText = "background: blue !important";
    else if (current === 1) vkCopy.document.body.style.cssText = "background: red !important";
    else if (current === 0) vkCopy.document.body.style.cssText = "background: magenta !important";

    current++;
    if (current > 4) current = 0;
  }, 50);

}, 5000);
```

Но этого эффекта не получается, тк фон меняется раз в секунду, если не дольше.
Если такой же скрипт выполнить, но для текущего окна, то экран действительно мигает.

Это какое-то специальное ограничение?

Comment: Попробуйте через [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Нет, так еще хуже стало - первая картинка через 10 сек появилась и всё

Comment: А вы следующий кадр requestAnimationFrame вызвали? И это только на вк или на любом адресе происходит?

Comment: На других адресах не проверял, но сомневаюсь, что разница есть. Но у меня появилась идея сделать это через css анимации.

Comment: А на счет requestAnimationFrame - да, первый раз дошел до первого "слайда". В следующий раз аж до третьего)